# Is there a way to feature-detect CSS3 resize on iframes?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, resize, browser-feature-detection

I have an iframe that is using the CSS3 resize style declaration:

```
iframe {
    resize: both;
}
```

I am using Modernizr to detect whether `cssresize` is supported in the browser so I can use the jQuery UI Resizable plugin in its place when the test fails.

However, Firefox doesn't seem to support CSS resize on iframes ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frf7G/)), and yet the Modernizr test passes anyway because Firefox does support textarea resizing. This leaves my iframe on Firefox without any CSS or JS resizing capability.

How can I use feature detection to ensure that the browser supports CSS3 resize on iframes?

Answer (score 0):

modernizr lets you create your own custom rules.  create one called `iframecssresize` that also checks that the browser + browser version is supported in addidtion to the `cssresize` feature is supported.

http://modernizr.com/docs/#addtest

Comment: Yeah browser detection is my last resort.  I really wouldn't like it to be my first and only as well, though.

Comment: Right now it looks like it might be your only option.  I played around with a fiddle example that tries to instantiate an iframe and set the property.  The property sets, it just doesn't have any affect.  http://jsfiddle.net/frf7G/4/ I also saw an open bug about this on mozilla's boards.